# Converting text field data to decimal value and back to string

Tags: swift

I converted text field string into a double to do calculations and then back to a string to output it on a label. I am now working with currency inputs so I need to convert it to a decimal rather than a double. Can someone help?

```
func calcTotal() {
    let totalConv: Double? = Double(totalTextField.text!)
    let tipConv: Double? = Double(tipTextField.text!)
    guard totalConv != nil && tipConv != nil else {
        return
    }
    let result = totalConv! * ((tipConv! / 100) + 1)
    let output = String(format: "$ %.2f", result)
    totalAmount.text = String(output)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to use `Decimal(string:)` initializer and `NumberFormatter` (currency style) to format your decimal value.

```
func calcTotal() {
    guard
        let totalConv = Decimal(string: totalTextField.text!),
        let tipConv = Decimal(string: tipTextField.text!)
    else { return }
    let result = totalConv * ((tipConv / 100) + 1)
    totalAmount.text = Formatter.currency.string(for: result)
}
```

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let currency: NumberFormatter = {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return numberFormatter
    }()
}
```